# "Floating in an asteroid," vs "floating on an asteroid."

Tags: word-choice

> The dog was in space, floating around in/on an asteroid.

Is the sentence above ambiguous? I'm not sure but I think it could mean that *the dog was floating on the surface of the asteroid* and also that *the dog was floating around in space together with the asteroid*

Which one makes the less ambiguous *in* or *on*? (I'm also open to other suggestions).

Comment: In does not work at all.

Comment: ‘In’ would imply that the dog was _inside_ the asteroid, which would only make sense if the asteroid was hollow … and even then, it would be quite odd. Then again, if you have a dog floating about on small celestial objects in empty space (and presumably breathing, so also wearing a space suit?), things are likely to be quite odd already.

Comment: Did you mean "in an asteroid _field_"?

Comment: English, like all human languages, evolved in a 1-G field, and has no resources adapted to weightlessness. If it ever happens that English needs words and prepositions to describe weightless experiences, they will develop. However, any present uses are strictly science-fictional.

Comment: @JohnLawler "However, any present uses are strictly science-fictional." Not at all: "The astronaut was in space, floating near ISS." What's fictional about that?

Comment: Was he at it or on it? And whose use rules? Certainly not NASA's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Floating ***near*** an asteroid if not touching, ***on*** an asteroid if  touching it.

> The dog was standing ***on*** an asteroid floating ***in*** space
>
> The dog was floating ***in*** space, pulled along by the gravity of a small asteroid

You can float ***in*** space all by yourself

If you are encapsulated in a space ship you are ***in*** it.

***In*** an asteroid does not work at all in your case.

This monster is ***IN*** an astoroid

[image]
<sub>(source: [geeknative.com](http://www.geeknative.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/starwars-spaceslug.jpg))</sub>

If he is near many asteroids, he is floating ***in*** an asteroid ***field***

[image]
<sub>(source: [scienceclarified.com](http://www.scienceclarified.com/scitech/images/lsca_0001_0001_0_img0015.jpg))</sub>

Comment: You beat me to it while I was looking for images

Comment: That sentence needs to go in primers everywhere. _"The monster is in the asteriod."_

Comment: In theory, you could be floating in a gas giant (if you manage to withstand the pressure) or maybe in a gas dwarf (if such a thing exists)

Answer (score 4):

I think *on* can work, but it would be an odd use of the word *on*. If you said:

> The dog was floating on Venus.

I’d assume that the dog was on Venus (that is, in its atmosphere), but it was floating (that is, not touching the planet’s surface).

You could get around the ambiguity by saying:

> The dog was on an asteroid, floating just above its surface.

---

As much as I like *near*, "near" can be quite far away when dealing with space travel.  If I said:

> The space probe was floating near Neptune.

it might still be thousands of kilometers away, ready to get into orbit. "Near" is a relative term.

This is one of those cases where, whichever preposition you opt to use, you'll have to rely on surrounding context to ensure readers interpret the preposition with the right usage and nuance of that word; a preposition (like *on* or *near* or *above*) isn't going to be able to do the job all on its own.

Comment: Well, what I want to say is that the dog is standing in the surface of a floating asteroid.

Comment: If the dog's feet are touching the asteroid's surface, use _on_, not _in_: "The dog is standing on the surface of a floating asteroid."

Answer (score 1):

This has been hinted at before, and "floating in" has largely been dealt with using monsters!

"Floating on" a solid body seems wrong to me, unless that body is what's causing you to float.  You could be "floating *in* the sea *on* a raft", "*in* the air, *on* a magic carpet", or even "*in* the air, *in* a helicopter".

An asteroid couldn't cause you to float, as it doesn't have anything to hold it up.

I would go with "floating just above the surface of an asteroid" (though to get really pedantic, it will have a finite gravity, so you won't float forever without some kind of rocket pack - unless you're orbiting the asteroid)

Comment: I thought asteroids were floating in space. So as an analogy the sea would be the space and the raft the asteroid?

Comment: @janoChen it doesn't quite work.  The simple difference is that the raft can support a passenger by pushing down on the sea, while the asteroid has nothing to push against.

Comment: Also you float ON a raft since it does not have sides but IN a boat because it does have sides

Comment: @mplungjan: Indeed - like Magic carpet vs. helicopter.

Comment: When you say that you are in space, floating around on an asteroid, it is clear that it is the asteroid doing the actual floating—you are just along for the ride because you are on the surface of the asteroid. I really don't understand your point about an asteroid not having anything to push against—describing objects that are in space without being in direct orbit of anything as ‘floating’ is quite common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I think the *around* makes a difference, and by the time I replied to the comment I forgot that was in the question.  So you're in firm contact with the asteroid, and the asteroid is floating freely - that's fine.  Note that I was (slightly over) simplifying, and that my "doesn't quite work" applied to the analogy. I still say "floating on an asteroid" doesn't work, while "floating around [space] on..." does.

Comment: @ChrisH: *floating in space* is [such a common phrasing](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=floating+in+space&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), it’s even [the title of a book](http://books.google.es/books?id=EgPUKEqQY3YC&dq=%22floating+in+space%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_21EUuzGNM2O7Qb1qIDwCg&redir_esc=y).  I’d agree that “floating on an asteroid” (no space) is a bit unclear, but “floating in space on an asteroid” seems fine to me (as does “floating around…”).

Comment: @PLL "floating in space on an asteroid" works for me too - I think "on an asteroid" needs something to qualify it and "in space, floating on an asteroid" doesn't do it for me.